# Sum rows based on values in a group

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to sum the subtotal of one group to the value of another group. Looking at the image, sum the two highlighted values and place the sum in the circled cell. This is what I've tried,
=iif(Instr("InpatientActivity,Observation",Fields!MetricGroup.Value)>0,sum(Fields!MTD.Value),sum(Fields!MTD.Value))

[image]

[image: RowGroupDetails]

Comment: Have you tried `RunningValue` yet?

Comment: I have not tried running value. Not sure how.

Comment: Can I define the group values that I want to add up? I want the total for only "InpatientActivity" and "Observation" and have that calculation show in the cell that is circled in the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
=SUM(
    SWITCH(
          Fields!MetricGroup.Value = "InpatientActivity", Fields!MTD.Value,
          Fields!MetricGroup.Value = "Observation" , Fields!MTD.Value,
          True, 0
          )
    )
```

For each row we evaluate the MetricGroup field. If it's one of the two literals then return the MTD value. The `True` in hte last pair of values acts like an `ELSE` so returns 0.

Finally, sum the results of the returned values.

---

**Edit**

---

If the expression is to be used inside a row group then the above will only return values from within that row group.

To include all values, you need to specify the scope of the expression. In this case you probably want to sum across the whole dataset.

Assuming your dataset is called `DataSet1` then change the expression to ...

```
=SUM(
    SWITCH(
          Fields!MetricGroup.Value = "InpatientActivity", Fields!MTD.Value,
          Fields!MetricGroup.Value = "Observation" , Fields!MTD.Value,
          True, 0
          )
    , "DataSet1")
```

**Note** The dataset name is case sensitive and must be enclosed in double quotes as above.

Comment: was there an error? were the numbers incorrect?

Comment: Sorry. No error. It didn't total. Just stayed the same.

Comment: Edit to show your report design, include row group details and I will look when I get a chance

Comment: If this worked, can you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark below vote up/down buttons to the left)